# Laravel 4: weird crash when clicking on an upload file form

Tags: php, laravel-4

i dont know if it can be helped but i have a regular form to upload files

```
  {{Form::open(array('action' => 'AdminController@addDocument','files'=>true)) }}
  {{ Form::label('file','File',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
  {{ Form::file('file','',array('id'=>'','class'=>'')) }}
  <br/>
  <!-- submit buttons -->
  {{ Form::submit('Save') }}

  <!-- reset buttons -->
  {{ Form::reset('Reset') }}

  {{ Form::close() }}
```

i know it works fine because it used to work fine, yesterday i tried to solve some other problems on my app and suddenly notice when i try to find a file to upload on my app firefox crash and close everything....i tried on chrome and i have the same problem....when i try to click on the file button  the explorer just crash...

i dont know if it would be useful but i have the crash report from firefox

```
AdapterDeviceID: 0x0116
AdapterDriverVersion: 9.17.10.3347
AdapterSubsysID: 56111b50
AdapterVendorID: 0x8086
Add-ons: %7Bb9db16a4-6edc-47ec-a1f4-b86292ed211d%7D:4.9.24,es-ve%40dictionaries.addons.mozilla.org:1.1.17,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:34.0.5,firebug%40software.joehewitt.com:2.0.7
AvailablePageFile: 4629495808
AvailablePhysicalMemory: 2200207360
AvailableVirtualMemory: 3700768768
BIOS_Manufacturer: American Megatrends Inc.
BlockedDllList: 
BreakpadReserveAddress: 44236800
BreakpadReserveSize: 41943040
BuildID: 20141126041045
CrashTime: 1419691945
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 00000000f0de0000
FramePoisonSize: 65536
InstallTime: 1419106959
Notes: AdapterVendorID: 0x8086, AdapterDeviceID: 0x0116, AdapterSubsysID: 56111b50, AdapterDriverVersion: 9.17.10.3347
D2D? D2D+ DWrite? DWrite+ D3D11 Layers? D3D11 Layers+ 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 929
StartupTime: 1419691021
SystemMemoryUsePercentage: 47
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
TotalPageFile: 8490917888
TotalPhysicalMemory: 4195950592
TotalVirtualMemory: 4294836224
URL: http://localhost/AsoYaracuy/public/admin/documents
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 34.0.5
Winsock_LSP: MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP] : 2 : 1 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IP] : 2 : 2 :  
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IP] : 2 : 3 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IPv6] : 2 : 1 :  
 MSAFD Tcpip [UDP/IPv6] : 2 : 2 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 MSAFD Tcpip [RAW/IPv6] : 2 : 3 :  
 Proveedor de servicios RSVP TCPv6 : 2 : 1 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 Proveedor de servicios RSVP TCP : 2 : 1 :  
 Proveedor de servicios RSVP UDPv6 : 2 : 2 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll 
 Proveedor de servicios RSVP UDP : 2 : 2 :  
 MSAFD RfComm [Bluetooth] : 2 : 1 : %SystemRoot%\system32\mswsock.dll
useragent_locale: es-ES
```

i think the error may be caused by php.ini but that's just a wild guess because that's one important thing i modified before getting the crash

Comment: So the browser crashes before you even submit the form?

Comment: I don't think that this problem is anyhow related to php or laravel because clicking the file button has nothing to do with them. This looks more like an issue with your os or a hardware defect. How about testing it on another system?

Answer (score 0):

Change File upload size in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M

post_max_size = 10M
```

and see whether it solves the problem.

Comment: Create a new form in an new page and see whether the problem occurs globally on the app or only on that page.